# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.cloud.sql.mysql.SocketFactory

Tags: java, apache-spark, google-cloud-sql, google-cloud-dataproc

I need help on identifying the issue when connecting to cloud sql from dataproc.
I need to read the table from cloud sql instance from spark.read.jdbc.
I am referencing this: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-sql-jdbc-socket-factory.

Added maven dependency:

```
 <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.cloud.sql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-socket-factory-connector-j-8</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.15</version>
    </dependency>

JDBC URL => s"jdbc:mysql://${OJDBCConfig.getString("database_name")}?cloudSqlInstance=${OJDBCConfig.getString("instance_name")}&socketFactory=com.google.cloud.sql.mysql.SocketFactory&useSSL=false&user=${OJDBCConfig.getString("user")}&password=${OJDBCConfig.getString("password")}"
```

I am also creating the fat jar for this, and also checked that my Jar contains the SocketFactory class.

Still I'm getting below exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: Could not create socket factory 'com.google.cloud.sql.mysql.SocketFactory' due to underlying exception:
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:425)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:408)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:918)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:897)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:886)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:860)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.createSocketFactory(MysqlIO.java:3330)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.<init>(MysqlIO.java:296)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.coreConnect(ConnectionImpl.java:2193)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2225)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2024)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:779)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:47)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:425)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:389)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:330)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcUtils$$anonfun$createConnectionFactory$1.apply(JdbcUtils.scala:63)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcUtils$$anonfun$createConnectionFactory$1.apply(JdbcUtils.scala:54)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JDBCRDD$.resolveTable(JDBCRDD.scala:56)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JDBCRelation$.getSchema(JDBCRelation.scala:210)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcRelationProvider.createRelation(JdbcRelationProvider.scala:35)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.resolveRelation(DataSource.scala:318)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.loadV1Source(DataFrameReader.scala:223)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:211)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:167)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.jdbc(DataFrameReader.scala:238)
        at com.express.processing.enrichment.TestMysqlConnection$.main(TestMysqlConnection.scala:16)
        at com.express.processing.enrichment.TestMysqlConnection.main(TestMysqlConnection.scala)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.JavaMainApplication.start(SparkApplication.scala:52)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:849)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:167)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:195)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:86)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$$anon$2.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:924)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:933)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.cloud.sql.mysql.SocketFactory
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.createSocketFactory(MysqlIO.java:3328)
        ... 37 more
```

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you aren't building the uber-jar correctly.

As of v1.0.15, uber-jars with the driver and dependencies are provided on the [Releases](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-sql-jdbc-socket-factory/releases/) page. Try giving one of those a shot and see if it works.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the suggestion , but getting same error ; I am using below command to launch the spark job. gcloud dataproc jobs submit spark --cluster=abc --project=xyz --region=us-central1 --class=com.abc.processing.xyz.TestMysqlConnection --jars=abc-xyz-2.0-SNAPSHOT.jar,mysql-socket-factory-1.0.15-jar-with-dependencies.jar .   I have also tested this with driver-jar-with-dependencies.